# how to add vertex colors to multiple objects using animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, vertex-colors

What are the steps to assign a list of colors to the vertex color of a list of objects? The 'set vertex color' node does not accept a
list of colors and a list of objects. So how to wrap this action into a loop or script?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Does each object have a constant vertex color?

Comment: That could be done using a script or a custom node. But vertex colors are stored at polygons loop level. So what do you expect about that? One color per vertex?

Comment: what is animation nodes?  I keep hearing about it.  Is it free?

Comment: @Millard Yes, it is free. https://animation-nodes.com/